# Conflict between bmp280 and esp wifi module?

Tags: arduino

I have written code for making work an esp and the bmp280 sensor separetely and they perfectly work, but once i try to implement them together, it stops at the "BMP280 test" message and i don't know how to correct his. I repeat, everything is correctly connected and if tested separately everything works. Actually, the whole code worked before adding the wifi module, while now i get this error. Does somebody have an idea of what could be wrong? Could there be conflict between the i2c communication of the bmp280 and the tx/rx of the esp? If yes, how could i solve that?

```
// LIBRARIES:
#include <WiFiEsp.h> // Include library for ESP8266-01 WiFi communication module
#include <Adafruit_BMP280.h>  // Include library for BMP280 sensor
#include <DHT.h>  // Include library for DHT22 sensor
#include <ThingSpeak.h> // Include library for ThingSpeak

Adafruit_BMP280 bmp;  // Initialize I2C Interface between Arduino and BMP280
DHT dht(3, DHT22);  // Initialize DHT sensor for normal 16mhz Arduino, DHT22 type sensor connected to digital pin 3

// CREATE ANOTHER SERIAL COMMUNICATION ON PINS 6 and 7
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
SoftwareSerial Serial1(8, 9); 
#define ESP_BAUDRATE  19200

WiFiEspClient  client; // Create an ESP8266-based WiFi client

// THINGSPEAK CHANNEL DETAILS
unsigned long ChannelNumber = 2414099;
const char * WriteAPIKey = "51KKPNEJT1V3LPB6";
unsigned int TemperatureFieldNumber = 1;
unsigned int PressureFieldNumber = 2;
unsigned int AltitudeFieldNumber = 3;
unsigned int HumidityFieldNumber = 4;
unsigned int RainFieldNumber = 5;
unsigned int LightFieldNumber = 6;


// SETUP
void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200); // Initialize serial communication at 9600 baud rate 
  dht.begin(); // Initialize DHT22 communication
  
    

  setEspBaudRate(ESP_BAUDRATE); // Initialize serial for ESP module (set the baud rate)
  Serial.print("Searching for ESP8266..."); 
  // initialize ESP module
  WiFi.init(&Serial1);
  // check for the presence of the shield
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    Serial.println("WiFi shield not present");
    // don't continue
    while (true);
  }
  Serial.println("found it!");
    
  ThingSpeak.begin(client);  // Initialize ThingSpeak

  // Check if BMP280 is correctly connected
  Serial.println(F("BMP280 test"));
  if  (!bmp.begin(0x76)) {
    Serial.println(F("Could not find a valid BMP280 sensor,  check wiring!"));
    while (1);
  }
  // Setting options for BMP280 as Default settings (from datasheet)
  bmp.setSampling(Adafruit_BMP280::MODE_NORMAL,     // Operating Mode
                  Adafruit_BMP280::SAMPLING_X2,     // Temp. oversampling
                  Adafruit_BMP280::SAMPLING_X16,    // Pressure oversampling
                  Adafruit_BMP280::FILTER_X16,      // Filtering
                  Adafruit_BMP280::STANDBY_MS_500); // Standby time
}

// LOOP
void loop() {

  // Connect or reconnect to WiFi
  if(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to WiFi");
    while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
      // PUT HERE YOUR WIFI NAME (instead of sara) AND PASSWORD (instead of saramande)
      WiFi.begin("WiFiCasa", "CasaMia2023!");  // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network
      delay(5000);     
    } 
    Serial.println("\nConnected.");
  }
  
  float temperature_bmp280 = bmp.readTemperature(); // Read data from BMP280 and store it to variables
  float pressure_bmp280 = bmp.readPressure()/100;
  float altitude_bmp280 = bmp.readAltitude(1013.25); // Read altitude based on the sea level pressure (1013.25 hPa)
  // Print on Serial Monitor data coming from BMP280
  Serial.print("Temperature(BMP280): ");
  Serial.print(temperature_bmp280);
  Serial.print(" °C  | ");
  Serial.print("Pressure: ");
  Serial.print(pressure_bmp280); 
  Serial.print("  hPa | ");
  Serial.print("Approx altitude: ");
  Serial.print(altitude_bmp280);  
  Serial.println("  m");     
  // Write data coming from BMP280 to ThingSpeak
  ThingSpeak.setField(TemperatureFieldNumber, temperature_bmp280);
  ThingSpeak.setField(PressureFieldNumber, pressure_bmp280);
  ThingSpeak.setField(AltitudeFieldNumber, altitude_bmp280);

  float humidity_dht22 = dht.readHumidity(); // Read data from DHT22 and store it to variables
  float temperature_dht22 = dht.readTemperature();
  //Print temperature and humidity values from DHT22 to Serial monitor
  Serial.print("Temperature(DHT22): ");
  Serial.print(temperature_dht22);
  Serial.print(" °C   | Humidity: ");
  Serial.print(humidity_dht22);
  Serial.println(" % ");
  // Write data coming from DHT22 to ThingSpeak
  ThingSpeak.setField(HumidityFieldNumber, humidity_dht22);

  int rain_analog = analogRead(A1);  // Read the value from rain sensor connected to analog pin A1 and stores it in the rain_analog variable
  int rain_percentage = map(rain_analog, 0, 1015, 100, 0);  // Map the analog value to a percentage (0-100)
  Serial.print("Rain intensity: ");  // Print on Serial monitor data coming from rain sensor
  Serial.print(rain_percentage);
  Serial.print("% - ");
  // Display corresponding message based on the value read by rain sensor
  if (rain_analog > 950) {
    Serial.print("NO rain   | ");
  } else {
    if (rain_analog > 712) {
      Serial.print("LIGHT rain   | ");
    } else if (rain_analog > 475) {
      Serial.print("MODERATE rain   | ");
    } else if (rain_analog > 237) {
      Serial.print("HEAVY rain   | ");
    } else {
      Serial.print("VIOLENT rain   | ");
    }
  }
  // Write data coming from rain sensor to ThingSpeak
  ThingSpeak.setField(RainFieldNumber, rain_percentage); 

  int light_analog = analogRead(A0); // Read the value from the photocell connected to analog pin A0 and stores it in light_analog variable
  int light_percentage = map(light_analog, 0, 1023, 0, 100);  // Map the analog value to a percentage (assuming a range of 0-1023)
  Serial.print("Light Intensity: "); // Print on Serial monitor data coming from light sensor
  Serial.print(light_percentage);
  Serial.println("%");
  // Write data coming from light sensor to ThingSpeak
  ThingSpeak.setField(LightFieldNumber, light_percentage); 

  Serial.println();  // Print a blank line on Serial monitor


  // Check the status of the operation to see if it was successful
  int x = ThingSpeak.writeFields(ChannelNumber, WriteAPIKey);

  if(x == 200){
    Serial.println("Channel update successful.");
  }
  else{
    Serial.println("Problem updating channel. HTTP error code " + String(x));
  }


  // wait 20 seconds
  delay(20000); 
}

/******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************      
* Name: setEspBaudRate      
* Description: This function attempts to set the ESP8266 baudrate. 
* Boards with additional hardware serial ports can use 115200, otherwise software serial is limited to 19200. 
*/     

void setEspBaudRate(unsigned long baudrate){
  long rates[6] = {115200,74880,57600,38400,19200,9600};

  Serial.print("Setting ESP8266 baudrate to ");
  Serial.print(baudrate);
  Serial.println("...");

  for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    Serial1.begin(rates[i]);
    delay(100);
    Serial1.print("AT+UART_DEF=");
    Serial1.print(baudrate);
    Serial1.print(",8,1,0,0\r\n");
    delay(100);  
  }
    
  Serial1.begin(baudrate);
}
```